# Change format of Date field of MongoDB in php

Tags: php, mongodb

My collection structure is as:

```
{a,b,time}
```

I am inserting data in the collection through a java service where a and b are integers and time is Date field.
On selecting a field from php I am getting the response as following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [b] => 19511297
            [time] => Array
                (
                    [$date] => Array
                        (
                            [$numberLong] => 1516688016000
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

How to get the time in the format as through the php function date('Y-m-d H:i:s) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your epoch timestamp is in milliseconds, so you need to do something like this:

```
$array[0]['time']['$date']['$numberLong'] = 1516688016000;

$timestamp = $array[0]['time']['$date']['$numberLong'] / 1000;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `$numberLong` contains unix-timestamp, hence you can try something like this:

```
$data[0]['time']['$date']['date'] = date(
  'Y-m-d H:i:s',
  $data[0]['time']['$date']['$numberLong'] / 1000
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use correct [MongoDB library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/) first. 
When you will extract data from database a datetime field in PHP would be represented as [UTCDateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php). 
When you had it converted to array it was like `['$date']['$numberLong']`. But you don't have to do that.

When you will get a list of documents from your collection, you can iterate over cursor and extract date and time in any convenient format using `toDateTime()` method in conjunction with `format()` later.

Look at the example below:

```
$cursor = $collection->find([]);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
  echo "\n" . $doc['time']->toDateTime()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

One of advantages here is that you are not loosing accuracy. The other advantage is that you can deal with timezones in a very efficient way.
For example, if you want to display date and time in IST timezone, you can do it like this:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
  echo "\n" . $doc['time']->toDateTime()->setTimeZone($timezone)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

I recommend you to take a look at [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/) (formerly Robomongo), it will help you to work with MongoDB.